# Purge a document containing special characters on CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, special-characters, purge

We are using version 1.6.1 of CouchDB and have discovered in a database a document with the id:

[image]

This document is currently "_deleted" and we cannot purge it with [the purge API](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/misc.html#db-purge).
When sending the request with the id and its last revision, the response returns as being 200 OK but does not show the document as being purged.

I did try to encode some special characters, but I got no results ...

**edit**

It seems that it is not possible for me to paste the text correctly in StackOverflow, here is an image of this text in notepad ++ really showing each character

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: "_deteled"? Surely you mean "_deleted"?

Comment: @RamblinRose yes indeed! :D

Comment: The first image above shows the document with the key "deleted:true" *not* "_deleted:true"....

Comment: @RamblinRose In the result of _changes, the property is called "deleted", but in the document itself, it is called "_deleted"

Comment: FWIW I've seen major typos hiding in plain sight in my time, hence the focus on 'deleted'.  If you haven't consider sifting through the couchdb github for a clue, for example [Stale couch view after purging document with conflicted revision tree](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/2045).